What is this double-decker jet that Qantas flew—or did it?
This is a screenshot from one of Petter's mentour pilot videos:

I thought two-floor passenger jets were impossible because they couldn't be evacuated in time.
I'm wondering if his editor accidentally included a shot of a simulated future aircraft.

There are numerous clips of actual double deck A380s in flight, and on the ground in the video you mentioned. Do you not believe the aircraft shown in all those clips are real?


thought two-floor passenger gets were impossible because they couldn't be evacuated in time

The video of the evacuation done for certification is available online and quite impressive since it must be done within 90 seconds.

What is this double-decker jet that Qantas flew—or did it?

Not only Qantas but also All Nippon Airways, British Airways, Emirates, Etihad Airways, Korean Air, Lufthansa, Qatar Airways and Singapore Airlines for a total 251 aircraft (half of that only for Emirates).
The A380 has actually been a very nice example of "the customer is always right" and that you should listen more carefully to their needs when you plan to build something for them (except maybe if you are Apple). The whole story is very well described in the Wikipedia entry.

... if you are Apple, or French. FTFY.

The screenshot depicts an Airbus A380. The A380 is notable (as the first paragraph of the Wiki article says) for being the only full-length double-deck jet airliner ever produced.
Qantas operates ten A380s, although they are slated to be replaced by the single-deck A350s beginning in the next decade.

Any idea who will be getting the double-deckers?  Or will they be scrapped?
